# Escape a dot in the author part of a bibtex entry

Tags: bibtex

When I include a dot/full stop (`.`) in the author part of a bibtex entry, it seems to just get stripped away. I've tried escaping it as `\.` and with braces, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

I encountered this with the [recommended citation](https://www.scipy.org/citing.html) of Python's SciPy library, reproduced below. As you can see, it includes a dot both on its own (in `SciPy 1.0 Contributors`) and as an accent (in `{\.I}lhan`). I solved this by replacing both occurrences with a macro that I defined in my document, but I would like to know whether a dot can actually be escaped.

(I was using `natbib`, as well as Springer's `svjour3` document class and `spbasic` bibliography style, in case it matters.)

```
@ARTICLE{2020SciPy-NMeth,
  author  = {Virtanen, Pauli and Gommers, Ralf and Oliphant, Travis E. and
            Haberland, Matt and Reddy, Tyler and Cournapeau, David and
            Burovski, Evgeni and Peterson, Pearu and Weckesser, Warren and
            Bright, Jonathan and {van der Walt}, St{\'e}fan J. and
            Brett, Matthew and Wilson, Joshua and Millman, K. Jarrod and
            Mayorov, Nikolay and Nelson, Andrew R. J. and Jones, Eric and
            Kern, Robert and Larson, Eric and Carey, C J and
            Polat, {\.I}lhan and Feng, Yu and Moore, Eric W. and
            {VanderPlas}, Jake and Laxalde, Denis and Perktold, Josef and
            Cimrman, Robert and Henriksen, Ian and Quintero, E. A. and
            Harris, Charles R. and Archibald, Anne M. and
            Ribeiro, Ant{\^o}nio H. and Pedregosa, Fabian and
            {van Mulbregt}, Paul and {SciPy 1.0 Contributors}},
  title   = {{{SciPy} 1.0: Fundamental Algorithms for Scientific
            Computing in Python}},
  journal = {Nature Methods},
  year    = {2020},
  volume  = {17},
  pages   = {261--272},
  adsurl  = {https://rdcu.be/b08Wh},
  doi     = {10.1038/s41592-019-0686-2},
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dots are removed by the bibliography style `spbasic.bst`. Either use a different bibliography style, or edit `spbasic.bst`:

1. Copy `spbasic.bst` to `myspbasic.bst`.
2. Edit `myspbasic.bst`: In `FUNCTION {format.names}`, change the lines

   ```
   format.name$
   remove.dots
   bibinfo bibinfo.check
   ```

   to

   ```
   format.name$
   % remove.dots
   bibinfo bibinfo.check
   ```

[image]

```
\documentclass{svjour3}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\cite{2020SciPy-NMeth}

\bibliographystyle{myspbasic}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doh, I didn't think this was something bibliography styles do. No wonder I wasn't able to find anyone else reporting the same problem. Using a different style isn't an option when submitting to Springer, thanks for explaining what line to comment out.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what's the rationale in the `remove.dots` function.

Comment: @oulenz You should be careful, though. If the article will appear in conference proceedings then it is probably fine, as Springer will probably not request the source files. However, if you have to submit the sources and Springer checks the typesetting, then you will have to fight for the dots ...

Comment: @gernot That's a very good point. I may stick with my macro workaround then.

Comment: @egreg My best guess is that its main purpose is to remove any dots after initials, although that could have been handled as part of the initialisation which is necessary anyway

Comment: @oulenz The periods after initials are removed anyway! If you comment out `remove.dot` from the `.bst` file, you clearly see it, because `format.names` has `"{vv~}{ll}{ f{}}{ jj}"` and `f` means no period is added to the initial.